# IReadOnlyCollection derived class extension returning original type

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, compile-time-type-checking

I'm a bit lost here (maybe because it's Friday)

I want to write a simple "throw if null or empty" extension helper that I can use in constructors like (e.g.)

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(params MyType[] parameters)
    {
        _parameters = parameters.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty();
    }
```

So I was trying to write this method like:

```cs
public static T ThrowIfNullOrEmpty<T, V>(this T? collection, [CallerArgumentExpression("collection")] string? paramName = null)
    where T : IReadOnlyCollection<V>
{
    if (collection is null ||
        collection.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"{paramName} is null or empty");
    }

    return collection;
}
```

But that doesn't work, as I get an "Arguments cannot be inferred from usage".

The issue here I that I have to use `ThrowIfNullOrEmpty<T, V>`, as `where T : IReadOnlyCollection<V>` requires a type parameter.

Isn't there a way to say "I don't care what `V` is, as long as `T` is a form of `IReadOnlyCollection`"?

Comment: Why not constrain `T` to `ICollection` and drop the `V` entirely?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Because I didn't know there's an `ICollection`. :shame:. But looking at the docs, I cannot find what its derived types are. Do all generic collections implement the `ICollection`? Else this would not be a solution.

Comment: You can check the list of derived types [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection?view=net-7.0) you can see that it includes a number of generic collections, including `Array` and `List<T>`. If you want to support all generic collections, then you could use `IEnumerable` instead.

Comment: With the `IEnumerable` approach, you would need to replace the condition with something like `collection?.GetEnumerator().MoveNext() is not true`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay but that will enumerate the collection. Doesn't seem very efficient, at least one allocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a method that takes any collection, and returns that collection of exactly that type, unless the parameter is null or an empty collection, then have it throw, without having to specify type parameters (so, leveraging inference).

In that case I'd go with the non-generic `ICollection`:

```
public static TCollection ThrowIfNullOrEmpty<TCollection>(this TCollection collection, [CallerArgumentExpression("collection")] string? paramName = null)
    where TCollection : ICollection
{
    if (collection is null || collection.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"{paramName} is null or empty");
    }

    return collection;
}
```

Comment: Like I said in the comments: looking at the docs, I cannot find what its derived types are. Do all generic collections implement the `ICollection`? Else this would not be a solution.

Comment: You click "More..." under "Derived" here and will find an enormous collection, pun intended: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection?view=net-7.0. It'll work just fine for most commonly used generic collections and arrays. If you need more, you create an overload.

Answer (score 0):

How about assigning with an out parameter?

```
parameters.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(out _parameters);

public static void ThrowIfNullOrEmpty<TElem, TColl>(
    this IReadOnlyCollection<TElem>? collection,
    out TColl? output,
    [CallerArgumentExpression("collection")] string? paramName = null
) where TColl : IReadOnlyCollection<TElem>
{
    if (collection is null || collection.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"{paramName} is null or empty");
    }

    output = (TColl)collection;
}
```

Comment: I know that `ICollection` is better, but `IReadOnlyCollection` doesn't inherit from it, if this interface must be considered, I think this is the most succinct syntax I can find.

Comment: I'm afraid you made a mistake, it is able to pass a field as an out parameter.

Comment: Wait you're right, I've never initialized fields that way and thought it only worked on local variables. Thanks.

Comment: that doesn't write fluently. E.g. writing `_parameters = parameters.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty().Operation1().Operation2()`, which we would have at some places in our code.